# How can I estimate this sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to estimate the sum

$$
\sum_{n=M}^\infty e^{-cn\ln(cn)},
$$

for $c<1$ in terms of $M$ ($M>1$) and $c$. Is this possible? I did not succeed so far...

Thanks!

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Why do you want such an estimate? Do you want to show convergence of the series?

Comment: I need it for an error estimate. My goal is (maybe) an estimate of the form $\leq D_{c,M}e^{-cM\ln(cM)}$ with known constant $D_{c,M}$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can rewrite this sum as
$$
\sum_{n=M}^\infty (cn)^{-cn}
$$
Each term in the sum is at most $(cM)^{-cn}$ (since $M\ge n$), so provided $M>\frac1c$, this bounds your sum by a convergent geometric series:
$$
\sum_{n=M}^\infty (cn)^{-cn}\le \sum_{n=M}^\infty (cM)^{-cn}
=\frac{(cM)^{-cM}}{1-(cM)^{-c}}=e^{-cM\ln(cM)}(1-1/(Mc)^c)^{-1}
$$
So this is not quite a constant times $e^{-cM\ln(cM)}$, but it's close. Is that helpful?

Comment: Yes, it is helpful! Thanks a lot.